# How to get the package name of the current foreground activity?

Tags: java, android

I looked around at similar questions and every answer has one thing in common and that's that they don't work on APIs greater than 21.

There's this snippet that only works on APIs of 20 and lower:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

And then there's the one that uses **UsageStats**. The bizarre thing is that despite being the most commonly posted answer on SO this method only works on one single API and that's 21, i.e. Android 5.0. It doesn't even work on Android 5.1.

Is there a modern way that works? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method that returns Observable of current top package likely work:

```
    public Observable<String> topPackageNameObservable() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        String topPackageName = "";
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                List<UsageStats> stats =
                        mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(
                                UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                                System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
                                System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
                if (stats != null) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                    }
                    if (!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        topPackageName = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    }
                } else {
                    topPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
                }
            } else {
                topPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return topPackageName;
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi what is the `fromCallable()` method? I'm getting the error that it doesn't exist in the `Observable` class

Comment: here I need Observable, you can change the return type to string and omit the fromCallable

Comment: CORRECTION: This doesn't always get the foreground activity. If there's a service running in the foreground then it returns the package name of that service instead of the foreground activity. Any fix for this?